# JavaScript Help in Adobe Acrobat DC pro

Tags: javascript, java, adobe

Can someone help me, I have create a java script to put in Adobe Acrobat PRO DC. My script is

```
var empt = document.forms["TESTING PDF"]["text3"].value; 
var nHide = empt == “” ? display.visible : display.hidden;
this.getField("Code").display = nHide;  
this.getField("description").display = nHide;
this.getField("Chief CO").display = nHide;
```

(getting `Error SyntaxError: Illegal Character 2: at line 3)` I can't figure out what its not liking

Comment: this.getField("Code").display = nHide;     this is line 3

Comment: Please be sure to use code formatters when posting actual code.

Comment: what is code formatters?

Comment: Im extremely new to this I just need help figuring out this code. why its giving me the error message.

Comment: I see no syntax error in the code you have posted.  But the error tells you exactly where to look in your source.  It shouldn't be hard to find.  Basically the error you posted does not patch the code you posted.

Comment: Are you able to attach screen shots on here? I can do that and show you

Comment: It doesnt like this line nhide = display.visible;      The error says only exactly what i put doesn't give me a symbol that is wrong or anything. I don't understand.

Comment: Yes you can attach images.  Just go back and edit your original post.  And "`it doesn't like this line nhide = display.visible;'".... that line isn't even in the code you posted.  You're using a ternary operator to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The quote characters you're using on the second line are curly quotes. Replace them with straight quotes.

That first line of code doesn't make sense for a PDF in Acrobat though, unless the document object is something you've created elsewhere.